# How to subscribe the topic only once

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a problem about how to sucscribe the topic only once,In some time, I only hope to get the first data from the topic, rather than change the publisher. So how should I do?
This is my code:

```
#include  <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/NavSatFix.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PointStamped.h>
static geometry_msgs::PointStamped point;

void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::NavSatFix::ConstPtr &msg)
{
  point.point.x=msg->latitude;
  point.point.y=msg->longitude;
  point.point.z=msg->altitude;
}



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "test");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  ros::Subscriber positions_sub = nh.subscribe("/POSITIONS", 3, &imageCallback);
  ros::spin();
}
```

In this code, I can get many points, but I only hope to get the first point. What should I change in tthe code  ?
THANKS!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270298/how-to-subscribe-the-topic-only-once/) by [hudaming](https://answers.ros.org/users/30924/hudaming/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-09-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While @bvbdort's answer will probably work, there is a convenience method that essentially does all that for you in a single line: [ros::topic:waitForMessage(..)](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/roscpp/html/namespaceros_1_1topic.html).

It also supports specifying timeouts, which `NodeHandle` to use and some other niceties.

---

Edit:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/NavSatFix.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PointStamped.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "test");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  sensor_msgs::NavSatFixConstPtr navsatfix_msg = ros::topic::waitForMessage("/POSITIONS");

  geometry_msgs::PointStamped point;
  point.point.x = navsatfix_msg->latitude;
  point.point.y = navsatfix_msg->longitude;
  point.point.z = navsatfix_msg->altitude;

  // do something with 'point'
  ...
}
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hudaming](https://answers.ros.org/users/30924/hudaming/) on 2017-09-06**:
Sorry, I can not get the solution. Can you give me an example?  My hope is to loop the imageCallback only once. Thanks!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-06**:
See my edit. This is somewhat pseudo-code though, I haven't (even) compile-tested it.

**Comment by [max11gen](https://answers.ros.org/users/38506/max11gen/) on 2019-01-24**:
@gvdhoorn Your code didn't work for me, because the return value of waitForMessage is a `boost::shared_ptr`. So in this case I'd need to change that to `boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::NavSatFix> msg = ros::topic::waitForMessage<sensor_msgs::NavSatFix>("/POSITIONS");`. You might want to fix this.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-24**:
Thanks, you were correct.

I've opted to use `NavSatFixConstPtr` though. It's more "ROS-onic".